# Permuting a linearly independent set of vectors to obtain a spanning set.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider a set of linearly independent vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_n \} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ such that for each $v_i$, the $2n^{\text{th}}$ entry is zero and every other entry is non-zero. If we define the permutation $P:\mathbb{C}^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ by its action on the standard basis as follows: $P(e_i)=e_{i+1}$ (where the index addition is modulo $2n$), then is $$\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots, v_n,Pv_1,\ldots ,Pv_n \} = \mathbb{C}^{2n} ?$$

Comment: Let $v_i = e_i$. Is your statement true?

Comment: @DuduBob Well I need the $v_i$ vectors to have non-zero entries everywhere except at the $2n$th position. So the $e_i$ vectors are not allowed!

Answer (score 0):

What about
$$v_1 = (1, 2, 3, 0)$$
$$v_2 = (1, 3\sqrt{2}i-1, -6, 0)$$
Then
$$-\frac{1+\sqrt{2}i}{3}v_1 + \frac{1+\sqrt{2}i}{3}v_2+2P(v_1) + P(v_2) = 0$$
As they are linearly dependent, they can't span $\mathbb{C}^4$.